# How to find the domain the of $x^2-25 \ge 0$

Tags: inequality

I am aware of how to find the domain but why does the $x$ greater than or equal to plus/minus $5$ become $x$ greater than or equal $5$ or $x$ less than our equal to $5$? Like why does the sign flip?

Comment: Note that $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$. So you go from $x^2-25\geq 0$ to $x^2\geq 25$, and since both sides are positive you can take square roots to get $|x|\geq 5$. That’s how you get $x\geq 5$ or $x\leq -5$.

Answer (score 2):

We can factorise the LHS to end up with something like this:
$$x^2-25=(x-5)(x+5)$$
So we have:
$$(x-5)(x+5)\ge 0$$
If we look on the number line, the set of values that satisfy the inequality would be $x\geq5 \cup x\leq-5$

---

It would be incorrect to write $x\ge\pm5$ . The right way to do so, would be to write: $|x|\geq5$. Arturo Magidin has provided more information about this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3814761/how-to-find-the-domain-the-of-x2-25-ge-0#comment7865533_3814761).